# imageantialias() doesn't seem to do anything on circles

Tags: php, gd

I create an image with:

```
$image   = @imagecreatetruecolor(320, 45) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream.");
imageantialias($image, true);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
```

Later, I add some text and on top of that, a shape:

```
imagearc($image, $x + 5, $y - 7, $size, $size, 0, 360, $color);
```

But the the circle is still very jaggy:

[image: jaggy circle]

I'm running php 8 with gd installed. I'm getting no errors.

Comment: maybe you need `imageantialias($image, true);` ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I do have true. I change it to false while trying to troubleshoot and see if there was a difference. I'll fix.

Comment: I just created lines with antialias and they look great. Maybe shapes simply don't work? The documentation didn't mention this, though.

Comment: Took a close look at docs: "Activate the fast drawing antialiased methods for lines and wired polygons."

I guess a circle isn't a wired polygon so doesn't work. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this guy has a whole web page devoted to algorithms to work around this limitation:  https://create.stephan-brumme.com/antialiased-circle/

Awesome work.

I went with "Wu's Algorithm" which provides the best quality. Works well.

Here's my version modified to use my global `$image` variable. It creates a perfect circle. The `$my_x` and `$my_y` are the x and y coordinates on the canvas.

```
function create_circle($my_x, $my_y, $size, $color) {
    global $image;
    $width = $size;
    $height = $size;

    $centerX = $my_x; $radiusX = ($width -20) / 2;
    $centerY = $my_y; $radiusY = ($height-20) / 2;
    static $maxTransparency = 0x7F; // 127
    $radiusX2 = $radiusX * $radiusX;
    $radiusY2 = $radiusY * $radiusY;
    // upper and lower halves
    $quarter = round($radiusX2 / sqrt($radiusX2 + $radiusY2));
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $quarter; $x++) {
        $y = $radiusY * sqrt(1-$x*$x/$radiusX2);
        $error = $y - floor($y);
        $transparency = round($error * $maxTransparency);
        $alpha  = $color | ($transparency << 24);
        $alpha2 = $color | (($maxTransparency - $transparency) << 24);
        setpixel4($centerX, $centerY, $x, floor($y),   $alpha);
        setpixel4($centerX, $centerY, $x, floor($y)+1, $alpha2);
    }

    // right and left halves
    $quarter = round($radiusY2 / sqrt($radiusX2 + $radiusY2));
    for ($y = 0; $y <= $quarter; $y++) {
        $x = $radiusX * sqrt(1-$y*$y/$radiusY2);
        $error = $x - floor($x);
        $transparency = round($error * $maxTransparency);
        $alpha  = $color | ($transparency << 24);
        $alpha2 = $color | (($maxTransparency - $transparency) << 24);
        setpixel4($centerX, $centerY, floor($x),   $y, $alpha);
        setpixel4($centerX, $centerY, floor($x)+1, $y, $alpha2);
    }
}

// helper function, draws pixel and mirrors it
function setpixel4($centerX, $centerY, $deltaX, $deltaY, $alpha) {
    global $image;
    imagesetpixel($image, $centerX + $deltaX, $centerY + $deltaY, $alpha);
    imagesetpixel($image, $centerX - $deltaX, $centerY + $deltaY, $alpha);
    imagesetpixel($image, $centerX + $deltaX, $centerY - $deltaY, $alpha);
    imagesetpixel($image, $centerX - $deltaX, $centerY - $deltaY, $alpha);
}
```